# Lubuntu no sound at all; no mute, alsa, pulse

Tags: 12.04, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

Apologies if this question has been answered already but I've scoured these forums and I haven't found anything that works.

I recently put together a low spec machine with plans on running Lubuntu 12.04. Installation went smoothly however there is no audio whatsoever.

I've tried installing pulseaudio & alsa mixer, made sure auto mute was disabled and played around with all of the settings to no avail.

I previously had installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the same machine and there were no audio issues, only when I made the switch to Lubuntu.

My machine's specs are:

AMD E-240 APU

2 GB 1066 RAM

AMD Radeon HD 6310 onboard graphics

Realtek ALC887 audio chipset

I am very grateful for any and all feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

In terminal run `pavucontrol`

1. In Configuration tab for Built-In Audio

   Profile : Analog

   Make sure HDMI is not selected.
2. Make sure volume is set in all other tabs of pavucontrol

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday (17-11-2015), I installed Lubuntu 12.04 LTS in Virtual Box on my Windows7 desktop computer with following hardware.
Amd Sempron (TM) 145 Processor
1GB DDR2 800 MHz PC 6400 of total 4GB of system RAM
Audio adapter ICH-Intel 82801AA-ICH

After Lubuntu 12.04 installation, there was no audio. I searched in Ask Ubuntu and got alsa mixer shell commands. I installed alsa mixer using terminal and got low audio. Again, I searched here and installed     pavucontrol and now low audio problem solved. I slided to just 125% volume on all sliders and audio is fine.

Thanks for help

Ananthakrishnan

Tamilnadu.

INDIA

Dated:18th Nov 2015