# No sound in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu

I Installed Ubuntu in laptop and audio was fine but I changed replaced Unity with Lubuntu and now audio is not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: what tests have you underwent before saying that sound id not working    will you please add a comment or modify your question

Comment: @agharehanabbas - What do you mean by test? I just tried to play a MP3 and youtube video in browser and both cased Audio didn't work

Comment: go to settings select sound option and then test speakers option

Comment: what was the output do you hear any sound while you click on right and left icons

Comment: There is no option called "settings" in Lubuntu or I'm unable to find

Comment: open the applications menu or lubuntu bash then enter system settings

Comment: what output have got by following those steps

Comment: I didn't get what to do you mean by application Menu and I typed "System Settings" in "Run" but nothing came

Comment: ok type system tools and see if the icon appears then click on it and type sound in the search box

Comment: This answer solved my problem http://askubuntu.com/a/320103/294979

Comment: as now your problem is solved you can close your asnwer

Comment: How to close it? Do you mean I should delete my question?

Comment: no you can see the option of close this question beside delete edit and share

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lubuntu no sound at all; no mute, alsa, pulse](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267531/lubuntu-no-sound-at-all-no-mute-alsa-pulse)

Answer (score 8):

Try `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and see if the sound comes back when you toggle the configurations.

Comment: Audio stopped working after my son used my laptop. I tried to enable it again, but fialed. For some strange reason the config dialogs in lubuntu showed "not muted". But with pavucontrol I saw that they were muted and I could enable it again. Thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

This may not help but I just installed lubuntu and tried to get my usb headphones to work but they did not...I installed adio mixer and pulse audio but neither worked. I then thought wth why not do a reboot..IT Worked!! I now have sound through my usb head phones...although my sound did work on my laptop speakers before....just and FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke (menu) -> Sound&Video-> PulseAudio Volume Control if you have it installed already.  Go to the [Output Devices] tab, that's the third one up at the top.  Find your output device in the list.  Make sure the Green globe-with-the-white-check button to the far right is *indented*, (shadowy), not unclicked out.  This connects your sound to your appropriate output device.  Make sure the blue master-volume slider is roughly in the middle, and not completely slid to the left.  You should hear a little "pock" when you reposition it, that tells you your headphones are turned on.

Sometimes this gets reset by itself on reboot.  You can check the panel to make sure your sound output is being sent to the proper device when you start your computer.

Comment: Brought up newish Lubuntu, plugged in headphones in front for first time while running.  Pulse Audio Volume Control gave blue volume bar, said *Headphones (plugged in)* which changed live with the plug so wires to jack physically connected, but no sound.  Headphones worked on Line Out jack in the back, so not blown headphones, not software driver problem.  Left physical headphone plug jacked in on the front, then rebooted machine.  It worked this time.  Conclusion:  Low-level hardware or driver feels better when headphones are plugged in upon booting.